# Getting an error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am trying to use `reactive forms` for dynamic values added on click of button. I am getting below error:

> formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in

Here is my example: [dynamic-reactive-forms](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-reactive-forms-add-zqaqjc)

I am new to `reactive forms`. Some code in `ts` file:

```
let numberOfTiles = document.getElementsByClassName("tiledata").length;
    if (this.t.length < numberOfTiles) {
      for (let i = this.t.length; i < numberOfTiles; i++) {
        this.t.push(this.formBuilder.group({
          tabName: ['', Validators.required],
          dashboardName: ['', Validators.required],
          linkTo: ['', Validators.required],
          linkSelected: ['', Validators.required]
        }));
      }
}

get f() { return this.dynamicForm.controls }
  get t() { return this.f.alltabs as FormArray; }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.dynamicForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    alert('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n' + JSON.stringify(this.dynamicForm.value, null, 4));
  }
```

Comment: The post is missing the HTML

Comment: @Vega created `stackblitz` for reference, https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-reactive-forms-add-zqaqjc

Comment: @Vega can you help?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div [formGroup]="alltabs">
```

Maybe you forget `alltabs`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this working **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-reactive-forms-add-v2skxx)**

Few things were missing from your code. I have changed your code a bit. Have a look on below code.

```
    <form [formGroup]="dynamicForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div formArrayName="alltabs">
        <div *ngFor="let item of t.controls; index as i" [formGroupName]="i">
```

Your `allTabs` is a FormArray so in HTML you have to define it like a formArray.
Obviously array has iterations so you have to loop through them and find your `formGroupName` which is always index, because each form group is on the each index of formArray.

Comment: I am not getting any values in alert. and still some errors in console. Please check.

Comment: in console: `ERROR
Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive. You'll want to add a formGroup
directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

Example:


<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
<input formControlName="firstName">
</div>

In your class:

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
firstName: new FormControl()
});`

Comment: Alert comes up when you put `type="submit"` on the button. Yes there are errors on the `addNewComponent()` function. I don't know what is going on in this function. But if you want the same form again on the click. Just push the form on a click. Shall I do that in the stackblitz?

Comment: if you can see, in my example I am loading component on click of `button` so on `save`, it should alert all the entered values.

Comment: Yes, you can do in that.

Comment: in `addNewComponent`, I am loading html from other component

Comment: are you getting?

Comment: Can you please help?